# SQL calculate the number of row in a specific range

Tags: mysql, sql

There's two table in my database:

Table A

```
Column_A1 column_A2
 A1         10
 A2         20
 A3         30
```

Table B

```
Column_B1 column_B2
 B1         11
 B2         21
 B3         31
 B4         29
 B5         30.5
```

I want to calculate how many row of table B match the following condition:

range:
A1±1,
A2±1,
A3±1,
...

for example:

B1∈[A1-1,A1+1]
count these row, return value 1.

B2∈[A2-1,A2+1]
count these row, return value 1.

B3∈[A3-1,A3+1]
B4∈[A3-1,A3+1]
B5∈[A3-1,A3+1]
count these row, return value 3.

Result should be like this:

```
Column_A1 column_A2 num_match
 A1         10        1
 A2         20        1
 A3         30        3
```

It's easy to use a loop to do this in other programming language, but what's the simplest way to make it in SQL ? Thanks.

Comment: The syntax for SQL will vary as per DBs, choose the tags as per the DB you are using

Comment: OK, I have edited the tags.@Sudipta Mondal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*)
        from b
        where b.column_b2 between a.column_a2 - 1 and a.column_a2 + 1
       ) as num_match
from a;
```

Note:  `between` is used suggesting that the bounds are included in the range.  If this is not the intention, then use explicit `<` and `>` logic.

Many databases would be able to take advantage of an index on `b(column_b2)` for this query.  You can test on MySQL to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` statement and filter on inequalities:

```
SELECT Column_A1,Column_A2,COUNT(*)
FROM A JOIN B ON column_A2-1 <= column_B2 AND column_B2 <= column_A2+1
GROUP BY Column_A1,Column_A2
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple query that matches with the way the OP expressed the goal of the statement:

```
SELECT
    a.`Column_A1`,
    COUNT(*) as `NumMatch`
FROM `Table_A` a
JOIN `Table_B` b
ON b.`column_b2` BETWEEN a.`column_A2` - 1 AND a.`column_A2` + 1
GROUP BY a.`Column_A1`;
```